# Can anyone identify this city skyline?

Tags: identify-this, photography

I have a video that shows a few quick glimpses out of a window and I have pieced together frames to make a complete image.  Can anyone identify this city?  Google Images, TinEye, and Wolfram-alpha have not recognized any of it.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you link the video? I'm much more reassured if it come from a show, and not a stalking question.

Comment: It is on HBO...they don't allow downloads from their site and require membership to access content.  These frames were in a reflection not meant to be noticed and I am trying to figure out where it was filmed.  Thanks!

Comment: @Craig What was the video?

Comment: It remember me something, but i cannot tell you now. Possibly you can put the individual buildings to the reverse search.

Comment: @Craig it's better than nothing to link the video even if it's behind paywall, perhaps someone else also has the same membership. But to prevent the trouble, could you also instead mention the title of the show, the episode, the timestamp, and also possibly the date & time of the broadcast? This is also to provide the context for this question to be more searchable, and thus more useful!

Comment: IMDB usually have comprehensive details about where movies and series have been filmed. Knowing from where the screenshot is taken, will make it much easier to identify the location.

Comment: Putting on hold until Craig identifies the video it was from.